# The UA Psionics wizard subclass feature Psionic Devotion modifies the Friends cantrip; how does it work?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, unearthed-arcana, psionics, cantrips

I am playing a wizard, and I am looking at choosing Psionics (from [Unearthed Arcana: Fighter, Rogue, Wizard](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-PsychicSoulPsionics.pdf)) as my Arcane Tradition.

The Psionic wizard subclass gets the [Psionic Devotion](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-PsychicSoulPsionics.pdf#page=4) feature at 2nd level, which lets the wizard learn one of the *friends*, *mage hand*, or *message* cantrips for free, and adds:

> While your psionic focus is on your person, you can cast the chosen cantrip as a bonus action, requiring no components, and with the modification listed below:
>
> ***Friends.*** When the spell ends, the target doesn’t become hostile to you.

For Psionic Devotion I like the look of *friends*, but I couldn't find clarification about the modification above. It reads as they know but don't care - but I'm pretty certain there are some NPCs who wouldn't take kindly to being charmed, so surely it depends on the NPC if they become hostile or not?

How does the Psionic Devotion feature's modification of the *friends* cantrip work?

Answer (score 3):

## It seems like they still know

The original text for *[friends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/friends)* (PHB, 244) states:

> When the spell ends, the creature realizes that you used magic to influence its mood and becomes hostile toward you.

The update on when you cast it through the Psionic Devotion is with the following modification:

> When the spell ends, the target doesn’t become hostile to you.

It doesn't modify that it realized you used magic, it just doesn't automatically become hostile.

Your belief that how an NPC reacts is up to the DM is correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106744/discussion-on-answer-by-nautarch-the-ua-psionics-wizard-subclass-feature-psionic).